# How to make a python script that encrypts any type of file

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to make my programs for the public (freeware) and I just want to know the code for making a file encrypted. (Python language 2.7.3)

Comment: What kind of encryption? What have you tried?

Comment: I recommend rot13, what it lacks in security it makes up for in ease of implementation

Comment: @MichaelDorst: you seem to be missing the humorous bone. A transplant is in order.

Comment: @GregS You're right, I should have looked up rot13 before I commented =) I thought he was being serious.

Answer (score 3):

here what you need

```
def encoder(path,pwd,topath):
    """
    @path: file path you wish to encrypt including filename
    @pwd: seek value 'you should remember that if you want to decrypt it'
    @topath: file path for encrypted file included filename
    """
    k = long(pwd) # key   # password in int
    f1 = open( path, "rb") # file path you wish to encrypt
    bytearr = map (ord, f1.read() ) 
    f1.close()
    f2 = open( topath, "wb" ) # path for encrypt file to write
    random.seed(k)
    for i in range(len(bytearr)):
        byt = (bytearr[i] + random.randint(0, 255)) % 256
        f2.write(chr(byt))
    f2.close()
```

Have you tried to search google for it, or even stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 for "Have you tried to search google for it, or even stackoverflow."

Comment: Hi - I've edited your code to use Python's bytearray builtin type  instead of convoluted mapping. Sometimes I notice  people don't know about it, and one of its use cases is exactly this.

Comment: And this uses, what, the Mersenne Twister as an encryption algorithm?

Comment: I know this small piece of code didn't offer much in it, but it did encrypt. and i hope that it will show Dawson a little bit what he asks "I just want to know the code for making a file encrypted.". I know there's nothing special in it. just a basic thought, pass it if you won't like it but before down voting it, edit it or paste a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [PyCrypto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)

You can also search for native python implementations, but they will be less efficient.